# For Validation is it possible to use pattern attribute on key press Event

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Here is my code : [Codepen](http://codepen.io/dannibla/pen/NbdaPQ)

Without any script, Validation Error message show on Form submit

```
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text1" placeholder="min-8, max-16, a-z, A-Z" pattern="^[a-zA-Z]{8,16}$" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Can we able to show Validation Error message **on key press** with small script **before form submit**....

So for i have tried this, but no use

HTML

```
<form> 
  <input type="text" name="text2" class="numberValid" placeholder="min-4, max-4, 0-9" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

SCRIPT

```
$('.numberValid').on('keypress', function () {
    this.setCustomValidity('');
 });
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can test input value on every `keyup` event (fired after the character has been added to input, `keypress` is fired before...).

Or as pointed out in comment, you may use the more suited `input` event fired when the value of the input is changed.

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
    $('.numberValid').on('input', function() {
      re = new RegExp(this.pattern);
      str = $(this).val();
      $('label').toggle(!re.test(str));
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text2" class="numberValid" placeholder="min-4, max-4, 0-9" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required>
  <label for="text2">Please enter 4 digits</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

To display error only on first keypress, just hide the label when DOM is loaded:

```js
$('document').ready(function() {
  $('label').hide();
  $('.numberValid').on('input', function() {
    re = new RegExp(this.pattern);
    str = $(this).val();
    $('label').toggle(!re.test(str));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form>
  <input type="text" name="text2" class="numberValid" placeholder="min-4, max-4, 0-9" pattern="^[0-9]{4}$" required>
  <label for="text2">Please enter 4 digits</label>
  <br/>
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Comment: `on('input')` may be a better choice of event.

Comment: @DanielAbraham I edited to hide error message on dom load. Your pattern attribute is used here and as previously said, you should not  use `keypress` event to validate the actual input value, rather use `keyup` or `input`. If the answer doesn't meet your needs, please refine your question.